# -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; not working on iPhone 6+ in Safari

Tags: html, css, iphone, safari, ios8

During testing on a site I am developing, I noticed that -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; that is applied to the container of my mobile menu does not work as expected on the iPhone 6+, but it working as expected on the iPhone 5.

After some Googling, I found a workaround that said adding a **border** to the same element fixes the issue, and it did briefly. But once the style was added to the CSS and the page was refreshed, it no longer worked until I rotated the phone, and then rotated it back - which leads me to believe this is some kind of bug with Safari on the larger iPhones.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Does anyone know any solutions that could fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: As a workaround - simply removing -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; fixed the issue of the content not scrolling at all. Now it scrolls, but it doesn't have the 'rubberband' characteristics of typical scrolling... which is fine for this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IOS 8 does not read -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch so you should also insert overflow:scroll to fix this problem on IOS 8.

in this case the versions which before 8 will read "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch" and the 8th version will read "overflow:scroll".

I faced the same problem and I fixed it in this way.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to "IOS 8 does not read -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch" ?

Comment: Here is the official documentation that suggests using `overflow:scroll`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-13-release-notes